# git format-patch : how can I get it to ignore already merged commits?

Tags: git, merge, commit, patch

I'm working on [my copy of the perl repository on github](https://github.com/shlomif/perl) and created a branch titled "perl-d-add-tests-2" for doing some changes, where I have commited some commits. I submitted these commits upstream and they were applied into "blead" (the main perl development branch). I pulled from the upstream repository, and did a "git merge" from blead into "perl-d-add-tests-2" and now I have tried running "git format-patch blead" there again and here is what happens:

```
shlomif@telaviv1:~/Download/unpack/perl/p5/git/perl$ git st
# On branch perl-d-add-tests-2
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
shlomif@telaviv1:~/Download/unpack/perl/p5/git/perl$ git diff blead | cat
shlomif@telaviv1:~/Download/unpack/perl/p5/git/perl$ git format-patch blead
0001-Made-c-line_num-working-again.patch
shlomif@telaviv1:~/Download/unpack/perl/p5/git/perl$
```

As one can see, "git format-patch" still generates the already applied commit. WTF?

How can I prevent "git format-patch" from doing that? I only want the unique changes, and previously when it happened I was told to open another branch and to "git cherry-pick" commits from there, but obviously this solution cannot scale, because it will litter my repository with branches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One simple option is to say specify which commits you want in a way that doesn’t include the older, already-applied ones.  The general syntax for referring to commits can be found in `git help rev-parse`; in this case, for example, saying “the last 5 commits on my current branch” would look like

```
git format-patch HEAD~5
```

Another possibility would be to rebase your `perl-d-add-tests-2` feature branch against the current `blead` branch.  IIRC, your earlier work on this branch was accidentally squashed into a single commit when it was applied to `blead`, so in this case you might have to do more manual cleanup than you’d expect.  If you want to try this approach, I suggest doing it on a throwaway branch, so you won’t lose anything if it goes badly.

```
# pull in upstream changes:
git checkout blead
git pull

# create and switch to a new branch "tmp":
git checkout -b tmp perl-d-add-tests-2

# rebuild this branch against your current "blead" branch:
git rebase blead
```

If you like the results, you can use the temporary branch in place of your feature branch:

```
# delete current feature branch:
git branch -d perl-d-add-tests-2

# rename the temporary branch back to the feature branch's name
git branch -m tmp perl-d-add-tests-2

# switch to the recreated feature branch:
git checkout perl-d-add-tests-2

# generate patches against blead:
git format-patch blead
```

Note that in the `git rebase blead` step you can also use the `-i` option, to interactively specify which commits to reapply to the current tip of `blead`.  That will open your `$EDITOR` on an agenda of commits to reapply; if you go down this route, you’ll probably want to explicitly delete the commits in that agenda that have already been applied to upstream `blead`.

Finally, you say that creating a fresh branch for this can’t scale, because you’d litter your repository with unwanted branches.  However, Git is happy for you to rename (`git branch -m`) or delete (`git branch -d`) branches at any time.  The only way that could cause problems is if other repositories downstream from you were depending on the deleted or renamed branches.  But in the common case of a local feature branch which noone pulls from and which you plan to submit upstream when it’s ready, there’s nothing to worry about.  So if the cherry-picking suggestion sounds good to you, you can do that, and delete the old version of your feature branch.